# Quickly generating the new SHA-1 hash for a file with data appended to it

Tags: hash, openssl, sha1

Here's my scenario:

- I have an existing file for which I've generated the SHA-1 hash, but not necessarily in the current run of my program.  So I have the hash, but no hash context to continue from (i.e. SHA_CTX in OpenSSL).
- I'll be appending new data to that same file and I need to recalculate the SHA-1 hash for it.

So my question is if it's possible to take advantage of the fact that I already have the hash for part of the file, and just continue the new hash calculation from that point in order to save time?  If so, how would I go about that?

Note that I'm currently using OpenSSL to generate my hashes, but I'm open to other options (as long as they're cross-platform).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input to SHA-1 contains the length of the message and some padding.
From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1#SHA-1_pseudocode):

```
Pre-processing:
append the bit '1' to the message
append 0 ≤ k < 512 bits '0', so that the resulting message length (in bits)
   is congruent to 448 ≡ −64 (mod 512)
append length of message (before pre-processing), in bits, as 64-bit big-endian integer
```

This means that you cannot simply continue from a SHA-1 digest, because it already contains in itself the size of the data and padding for the block it was calculated for.

The internal state of SHA-1 is 160 bits, without them you cannot calculate a new SHA-1 digest for the longer block. That's the reason the OpenSSL functions have a "final" call - it has to be called once at the end. Until then you have to keep the internal state somehow (with the SHA-1 context or in other ways).

Comment: Right -- that makes sense.  So just to be clear: if I saved the contents of the context data structure before I performed the finalize call, then reloaded it at a later time and continued processing the new data, that should work right?

Comment: @codely - yes, the context holds everything you need. As far as I can see it's a "flat" structure, so you can just copy the whole thing (e.g. using memcpy) and save/load using fwrite/fread (on the same machine! otherwise you'd get into trouble).

Comment: Perfect.  I'll just verify it works by comparing a SHA-1 hash of the full file to one generated from part of that same file, saving the context, loading it, and continuing.  Just to cover all possible sources of discrepancy, I'll do the loading and continuing in a separate process.